# What am is missing? (API CORS)

Tags: plugins, authentication

I created a plug-in that retrieves data from an api(at least tries to!). This is the code of the function.

```
function call_back(){

     
$apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$response = wp_remote_get ('http://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/LD-1',$args);
$args = array(

    'headers' => array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => 'Basic ', $apiKey,
    )
);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
echo '</pre>';
};
```

The api key that i use works, used it in postman. But the problem i get is that in WP i get:

```
"string(95) "{"errorMessages":["Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."],"errors":{}}""
```

I do have permission and the issue does exist, the problem is with authentication. For some reason i don't get access. Any idea on why?

Comment: You have to declare `$args` first

Comment: What do you mean? Putting $args above the response?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you that helped me alot! But there was one more problem and that was the `"'Authorization' => 'Basic ', $apiKey,"` part. I just needed a dot before $apiKey. Thanks again for your help!